# SQLite Update Limit

Tags: c#, sql, system.data.sqlite

How can I use the `LIMIT` clause in an `UPDATE` in SQLite?

I tried adding the option to the SQLConnection but it didn't work, I get the error `SQL logic error near LIMIT`

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + outpath + ";Version=3;foreign keys=true;sqlite enable update delete limit=true");

string sql = @"
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET userId = @userId2
    WHERE userId = @userId1
    LIMIT @amount
";
```

In case it's not possible to make the `LIMIT` clause work, how else would I limit the amount of records that are updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **subquery** to fetch records viable for `userId` field update.

Let's say this is your `MyTable` contents:

```
id  userId
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   2
```

If you want to change only 2 records of `userId=1` into `userId=3`. You can select those 2 records by ID:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET userId=3
WHERE id IN 
    (select id 
     from users 
     WHERE userId=1 
     LIMIT 2)
```

The subquery gets `id` values of first 2 records matching the criteria and passes them to `WHERE id IN`.

The first 2 records will be affected, because no `ORDER BY` have been used within subquery.